# Bloque de Anuncios Admob y Android

Tags: android, admob

Buenos días hace poco publiqué una app en Play Store, contiene un banner simple, ahora estoy pensando en colocar otro banner en otra actividad, quería saber si alguno de ustedes ha utilizado el mismo ID de bloque de anuncios para diferentes banner o necesariamente tendría crear un bloque de anuncios nuevo, también me gustaría saber cual es la diferencia en tener 2 con el mismo ID o con diferente ID.

La unica información que encontré acerca de esto fue:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar y gracias de antemano :D

Comment: Si utilizas el mismo código de anuncio para varios funcionará pero no podrás ver estadísticas detalladas por anuncio. La manera correcta sería crear en Google Admob un anuncio por actividad y identificarlo como tal.

Comment: Donde podria ver las estadisticas detalladas de cada uno? no logro ubicarlo

Comment: Desde la consola de Google Admob. En la página principal antes de la tabla de apps hay un enlace llamado "Administrar aplicaciones", desde hay puedes ver los anuncios vinculados a cada app.

Comment: Gracias! Hay alguna forma de ver que tipo de anuncios son los que generan mas clicks?